# Directory /docker_data too large

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, centos, blob

I'm a little bit newbie at Docker and Kubernetes. I did some research but I couldn't find a proper way to verify this.

I have a development environment that runs Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe (verified with `docker --version`) and several containers in it, orchestrated with Kubernetes.

I have a folder called /docker_data/images/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256 with more than 100 GB that I can't find any relation with my environment. I also have a folder /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256 that contains images.

My hard drive reached 85% and all of my pods are getting the Disk Pressure error, and I believe this is the reason.

My /etc/docker/daemon.json don't give me any hints either:

```
  {
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
  "max-size": "100m"
     },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
  "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ],
  "insecure-registries" : ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000"]
  }
```

I already tried `docker system prune -a` but no space was reclaimed.

My question is, how can I verify that this directory is important for my environment to run properly? I'm planning to remove it but I don't know if it is essential.

I'm using CentOS 7 here.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Looks like the directory stores your image registry, while the other stores downloaded images. This is likely duplicating your image data.

Comment: I'm having that same impression, but I couldn't find a way or configuration file to verify that (yet).